# Using items in the background of a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsScene where I initially drew the background in the drawBackground() function. However, this required quite a few calculations and turned out to be pretty slow so I created a bunch of items instead. This had the expected speedup.

My question: is there a way to treat these items as the background? Would it even matter if I treated them as background items?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three layers in terms of QGraphicsScene (see Qt docs):

- QGraphicsScene::ItemLayer

> The item layer. QGraphicsScene renders
>   all items are in this layer by calling
>   the virtual function drawItems(). The
>   item layer is drawn after the
>   background layer, but before the
>   foreground layer.

- QGraphicsScene::BackgroundLayer

> The background layer. QGraphicsScene
>   renders the scene's background in this
>   layer by calling the virtual function
>   drawBackground(). The background layer
>   is drawn first of all layers.

- QGraphicsScene::ForegroundLayer

> The foreground layer. QGraphicsScene
>   renders the scene's foreground in this
>   layer by calling the virtual function
>   drawForeground(). The foreground layer
>   is drawn last of all layers.

Threrefore, there is no *legal* way to put an item into the background layer.
However, you could use QGraphicsItem Sorting to place some items behind others, making them to appear as a *background*.

Comment: I guess I could still put the stuff in drawBackground() but cache all the calculated stuff as it is static. However, this results in two phases for the background which I don't like.

Do you know if there are any drawbacks to using items instead? They're a bunch of text and rect items with some transparencies..

Comment: I think the best way is to use items. Don't know any drawback.